# How can I play 5.1 HDMI audio and stereo audio (speaker jack) at same time?

Tags: audio

I play out Blu-Ray 5.1 movies thru the HDMI output on my video card. I also want to get a simultaneous stereo output thru the on-board audio jack (green). Trouble is when I plug into the stereo jack, the HDMI audio is stopped. How can have both outputs from same source?

Comment: Check you sound adapter's software to see if it allows you to configure what you want (perhaps edit your question to include the make/model of the adapter, and what you've tried already).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot in the dark:

Control Panel > Sounds

Highlight "HDMI" and go to Properties.

On the Advanced tab, uncheck both "Exclusive mode" options.

Do the same for "Speakers" in Control Panel > Sounds. You may need to further tinker with the mixer after plugging the HDMI in.

Sorry I cannot test this myself. I hope this helps!